# How to get SQL DB Info using Rest API C#

Tags: c#, rest, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to collect the list of all Azure SQL Databases across all of our subscriptions using Rest API.
I need **Database Name, Used Size and Cores Allocated**.

I'm trying to use below Rest API URL. Man, it is so easy to get it via PowerShell (***Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.SQL/Servers/Databases***) this Rest API requirement is making me go bonkers past 2 days.

```html
/subscriptions/{SubscriptionGUID}/resources?$filter=resourceType%20EQ%20'Microsoft.SQL/Servers/Databases'&api-version=2019-05-10";
```

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: I need to get the list of SQL Databases from Azure Subscription using Rest API.

Comment: Now. What is the error you face?

Comment: I'm not getting any results. I'm getting empty results.

Comment: Please try the api via the page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list.

Comment: Do you have any update?

Comment: That was the first place it tried. It is not list SQL servers. the get resources rest API is resulting only storage accounts

Comment: Could you please check if you have provide right subscrption and the subscription has sql server?

Comment: Yup. I checked. its only is giving Storage acounts.

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshot of powershell result and rest api result?